# Mongoosejs Изменение объекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Схема

```
const usersSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  username: String,
  polls: [
    {
      poll_id: Number,
      status: String,
      question: String,
      answers: [
        {
          number: Number,
          answer: String,
          votes: Number,
          voters: [
            {
              first_name: String,
              last_name: String,
              username: String,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

Пример документа

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5856a3545b3b5821a08c2058"
    },
    "id": 98245540,
    "first_name": "Danil",
    "last_name": "Belkov",
    "username": "dbellkoff",
    "polls": [
        {
            "poll_id": 1,
            "status": "Creaaaaating",
            "question": "asd",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5856a3f44f58c22e3821a049"
            },
            "answers": []
        },
        {
            "poll_id": 2,
            "status": "Creating",
            "question": "asdd",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5856a3f44f58a22e3821a049"
            },
            "answers": []
        }
    ],
    "__v": 1
}
```

Мне нужно искать в polls все опросы со статусом "Creating" и добавлять в эти опросы ответы в массив answers.

Подскажите, могу ли я получить доступ к опросу по

```
"_id": {
   "$oid": "5856a3f44f58a22e3821a049"
 },
```

Если да, то как? По Model.find*ById('5856a3f44f58c22e3821a049') возвращает null

Если нет, подскажите оптимальный способ решения мой задачи.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.update(   
      {"polls.status": "Creaaaaating"},   
      {answers: {$push: "Новый ответ на все вопросы со статусом Creaaaaating"}})    
      .exec( (err, docs) => {
         //your code
       })
```

Можно искать и по айдишнику, `Model.findOneAndUpdate ({"polls._id": yourPollsId})`